# How do I set a Preprocessor Definition in Gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but how do I define a preprocessor definition.  In Visual Studio I can just go to C++ -> Preprocessor and set a list of definitions there.  But I'm struggling with that in my Android gradle build.

I need to define DEBUG, as to satisfy the following condition

```
#if (!defined(NDEBUG)) && (!defined(DEBUG))
```

I've tried adding -DDEBUG, but that didn't seem to work.  I've struggled finding documentation on what needs to be done.

```
    cppFlags.addAll(["-fexceptions", "-std=gnu++11", "-DDEBUG"])
```

Here is my NDK build block
        // defines the NDK build
        ndk {
            moduleName "mymodule"

```
        toolchain = "clang"

        // If switching to GNU, here are the values to replace with
        stl "gnustl_shared"
        cppFlags.addAll(["-fexceptions", "-std=gnu++11", "-DDEBUG"])


        // when adding system library dependencies, they are added here
        ldLibs.addAll(["log","atomic"])

        // C include directories
        CFlags.addAll(["-I${file("src/main/jni/folder1")}".toString(),
                       "-I${file("src/main/jni/folder2")}".toString()
        ])

        // C++ include directories
        cppFlags.addAll(["-I${file("src/main/jni/morestuff")}".toString(),
        ])
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, glad to know that you solved your problem. I had a similar question about define compiler preprocessor in gradle and I'm still struggling to find a answer. Not sure if you could have a answer? Here is my question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860467/android-studio-how-to-define-custom-macros-in-build-gradle-for-different-build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have both `CFlags` and `cppFlags` set. Are you certain you are adding the DEBUG flag to the correct one? If you are dealing with a shared library, it may need your flag in `CFlags` rather than `cppFlags`.

I would try adding your DEBUG flag to `CFlags` and see if that works:

```
CFlags.addAll(["-DDEBUG"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that's exactly what I was doing wrong!