# Android Studio: How to define custom macros in build.gradle (for different build variants) and let native C/C++ code detect them?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to define some custom macros such as "**DEBUG**", "**RELEASE**", "**DEMO_VER**" and "**FULL_VER**" in Android Studio **build.gradle** file so that my C/C++ code can detect them like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   ...
#else //RELEASE
   ...
#endif
```

or

```
#ifdef DEMO_VER
   ...
#else //FULL_VER
   ...
#endif
```

My understanding is that these macros should be defined as g++ compiler options in the build variant blocks like the following code:

```
buildTypes 
{
    release 
    {
        cmake   <<====== Error!!!!!: could not find method cmake() for ...BuildType
        {
            cppFlags += "-DRELEASE"
        }
    }
    debug 
    {
        cmake   <<====== Error!!!!!: could not find method cmake() for ...BuildType
        {
            cppFlags += "-DDEBUG"
        }
    }
}
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors 
{
    demo 
    {
        cmake   <<====== Error!!!!!: could not find method cmake() for ...ProductFlavor
        {
            cppFlags += "-DEMO_VER"
        }
    }
    full
    {
        cmake   <<====== Error!!!!!: could not find method cmake() for ...ProductFlavor
        {
            cppFlags += "-DFULL_VER"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can not use "**cmake**" inside either "**BuildType**" nor "**ProductFlavor**", the method can not be found. 
So what is the correct way to pass in compiler macros for different product flavors / build types?

Answer (score 4):

Found answer myself: The "cmake" method belongs to class "externalNativeBuild" class, therefore it needs to be embedded inside "externalNativeBuild" block, like this:

```
release
{
        externalNativeBuild
        {
            cmake
            {
                cppFlags += "-DRELEASE"
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

Now all the preprocessors defined in **build.gradle** are passed into the C/C++ compiler.

Comment: Does the IDE correctly react to these defines for you, i.e. shadowing code paths removed by the preprocessor? We pass preprocessor defines the way you describe but the IDE does not correctly update (still greys out active code paths).

Comment: I made a quick test. The result is that the IDE does not grey out the disabled code blocks, which is bad. But the good thing is that the prerpocessors are indeed passed in, so they take effect during compilation. Hope Android Studio will improve this in the future.